# How to append 1 new column (mrt with student having student fare, senior having senior fare and adult/national serviceman have adult fare)

Tags: dataframe

[image]
I would like to append the new student fare in a new column under concession dataframe with the students(1200) having the same price while same adult price for national serviceman and adult(4050) and seniors(2070) and a last new column single trip with all having the same price(6900)?

I tried using iterrows but to no avail, are there any other possible methods?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
df['MRT'] = df['cardholders'].apply(lambda x: 1200 if 'Student' in x  else (2070 if 'Senior' in x else 4050))
df
Out[143]: 
          cardholders   MRT
0     Primary Student  1200
1   Secondary Student  1200
2  University Student  1200
3      Senior Citizen  2070
4  Adult Monthly Pass  4050
```